# Firebug indicates two requests in an SVG with xml:base attribute

Tags: html, xml, svg, firebug

I have a working SVG drawing in an `<iframe>` with some `<image>` elements.  The drawing is located in one location; the images relative to another.  Here is the HTML:

```
<iframe src="/howl/svg/id/482?width=535&amp;height=325"></iframe>
```

Here is the SVG that is the source for the `<iframe>`:

```
<svg xml:base="/howl/">
   <svg width="535" height="325" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <g id="svg_1">
        <image xlink:href="file/id/472" id="svg_4" height="516" width="631" y="-95.5" x="-48"/>
     </g>
   </svg>
</svg>
```

Everything displays properly.  However, according to firebug, I'm getting two requests:

1. `http://localhost:8086/howl/file/id/472` - This is correct and loads properly.
2. `http://localhost:8086/howl/svg/id/file/id/472` - This is incorrect.

Interestingly, the incorrect request does not return a 404, but churns indefinitely in Firebug with a mysterious spinner.  I am also unable to click-inspect the request.  If I type this URL directly into my browser:

```
http://localhost:8086/howl/svg/id/file/id/472
```

I get a 404 Not Found, which is what I would expect, but not what Firebug reports.

Is this a problem with my SVG?  A Firebug error?  Is the second request even being made?

Thanks!

**Updated**: I've included my entire source code.

Comment: We need more information.  Link to the page or provide enough, complete, code to duplicate the problem.

Comment: @Brock Adams I've included the entire source code.  Thanks!

Comment: Tomcat request logging (which I just figured out) indicates that those extra GET requests are not happening.  I posted to Firebug Forums and will post an answer when I get one.

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing these requests, but it's just what Firefox does. So, it doesn't seem to be Firebug problem (other Firefox monitoring tools show the same).

I don't have much experience with SVG, but if I replace the:

```
<svg xml:base="/howl/">
```

with

```
<svg>
```

I see only two requests. What is the xml:base for?

Comment: Firefox isn't actually making the additional request (according to Tomcat).